# Key Value List from File In Spark Scala

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, key

If I have a file like:

```
A 2 4 5 6 8 56
B 5 6 7 9
...
Z 6 6 5 89 78 0
```

then if I would like (k, v) pair RDD with v as List or other Iterator as follows:

```
A, List(2,4,5,6,8,56)
B, List(5,6,7,9)
...
```

what is the easiest way to do this?

And what if I wanted:

```
A, List(List(2,4),List(5,6),List(8,56))
...
```

I can see how procedurally I think. But I think I might be overlooking a simpler functional approach.

Comment: `map` using `split` and then `keyBy`? What have you tried so far? Did you go through RDD API docs?

Comment: may be that simple, split clear, but I thought it would say too many values from reading but will check

Comment: keyBy still leaves the first value there if I do val RDD2 = varReadingsFile.map(line => line.split(" "))
          .keyBy{a => (a(0))} . I am looking for the easiest way, so you confirm my thoughts, particularly on second example, some more thinking to do

Comment: Next time - include the code of such attempts in the post, would make it much easier to answer

Comment: indeed, my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sc.textFile("/input/files").map { str =>
  val parts = str.split(' ')
  (parts.head, parts.tail.map(_.toInt).toList)
}
```

And grouped into a list of 2-element lists:

```
sc.textFile("/input/files").map { str =>
  val parts = str.split(' ')
  (parts.head, parts.tail.map(_.toInt).toList.grouped(2).toList)
}
```

Comment: Realized that SCALA is indeed a question of knowing this and that. Excellent! Useful for others I am pretty sure